# Why/how is javascript interpreting this "list" of bare numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Due to a typo I made today, I started messing around with my `node` repl and am trying to figure out why this is happening on my machine both in Chrome and Node (v6.9.2).

```
> 1, 2, 3, 8
8
> a = 1, 2, 3, 8
8
> a
1
> (1, 2, 3, 8).toString()
'8'
```

What is the javascript engine seeing/parsing/doing here? I can't help but feel confused by what's going on and would appreciate some direction on where I can go to learn more about it.

Comment: a comma is like a semicolon, only it concatenates multiple statements as one. you're assigning the number 1 to `a`, and then following it with separate statements of numbers which dont do anything.

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the comma operator `,` that's doing its magic here. `expr1, expr2` will evaluate both expressions, but return only the latter.

If `expr1` has no side effects, then the comma operator is really not very useful, as it will be functionally the same as just `expr2`:

```
var a = (2, 3); // 2 and 3 are both evaluated, but final result is 3; no side effects
var b = 3;    // functionally equivalent to the above
```

Where it makes a difference is when `expr1` has side effects, such as calling a function, or changing a variable:

```
var a = 0, b = 3;
var c = (++a, ++b); // ++a has the side effect of incrementing a

var d;
d = 5, 6;     // (d = 5) has the side effect of setting d to 5

// now a = 1, b = 4, c = 4, d = 5
```

One case where this is useful is when you have a for loop with two simultaneous variables that you want to increment:

```
for(let i = 0, j = 5; i < 3; i++, j++) {
                          // `------´  comma expression, so both are incremented
  console.log(i, j);
}

// prints:
//   0 5
//   1 6
//   2 7
```

Note also that the comma operator is different from the statement separator `;`, so the following won't work as expecte

---